# Evaluate $f^{\prime \prime}(z)$ using Cauchy's inequality.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose an entire function $f$ satisfies $|f(z)| \leq \pi|z|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

(a) Evaluate $f^{\prime \prime}(z)$ for each $z \in \mathbb{C}$ using Cauchy's inequality.

By applying the Cauchy's estimate

($|f^n(a)|\leq \frac{Mn!}{R^n}$), we have
$|f''(0)|\leq \frac{2\pi R}{R^2}$ and by analyticity we can let $R\rightarrow \infty$ to get $f''(0)=0$, but what about other points? How to get the bound $M$ of $|f(z)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|f(z)| \leq \pi R$ when $|z|=R$. Hence $|f^{(n)}(0)| \leq \frac {\pi Rn!} {R^{n}}$ and letting $R \to \infty$ gives $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n >1$. The power series expansion now shows that $f(z)=f(0)+f'(0)z$ for all $z$.  Hence $f''(z)=0$ for all $z$.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply Cauchy's estimate for $f''$ to a disk of radius $R$ with arbitrary center $a$, that gives
$$
 |f''(a)| \le \frac{2 \pi(|a| + R)}{R^2}
$$
and with $R \to \infty$ you can conclude that $f''(a) = 0$ for all $a \in \Bbb C$.